# using ILgenerator to overload a method, using items data from an ArrayList field

Tags: c#, cil

I am creating a class, call it CallerClass and a method override in CallerClass

The CallerClass overridden method (from its base class) needs to call a constructor or a method for another class,call it OtherClass, but I don't know which class this is at runtime.

The OtherClass instance and parameters for constructors or methods are stored in an ArrayList which is a field of the CallerClass's parent class.

How do I perform the override?

Comment: You can't use simple reflection? Can you share a small code example that demonstrate how that ArrayList would look like?

Comment: something like this?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  I need to generate that code dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If Reflection really does not suit your needs, you can override/extend methods via IL Weaving. One tool I can suggest is Afterthought: https://github.com/vc3/Afterthought/wiki

In the following example I define an Amendment which amends all subclasses of CallerClassBase - this is introduced as the base class of your CallerClass

```
class MyAmendment<T> : Amendment<T, T> where T : CallerClassBase
{
    public override void Amend(Method method)
    {
        method.Before(amended =>
            {
                if (amended.GetType() != typeof(CallerClassBase))
                {
                    // Implement your logic here
                }
            });
    }
}
```